# Install other scala libraries on EMR notebook

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I have an EMR scala notebook, what I'd like to do is to install a library for plotting spark data. The library is called [Vegas](https://github.com/vegas-viz/Vegas). 
How can I do it? 
Thanks

Comment: EMR notebooks use Livy as backend for spark. You could specify the maven coordinates of the jar to `livy.spark.jars.packages` and give it a try.

Comment: Should I do it by specifying some input args as I  start the EMR notebook?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using *Apache Toree (which provides the Spark, PySpark, SparkR, and SparkSQL kernels)* in EMR you can do the following:

```
%AddDeps "org.vegas-viz" %% "vegas" % {vegas-version} --transitive
```

An it will start to download the jars and you will be able to use vegas in your notebook

Comment: I am using the EMR notebooks not Apache Toree. I don't belive it'll work

Answer (score 2):

You can configure scala dependencies within the notebook as,

```
%%configure -f
{
"conf": {"spark.jars.packages": "//maven coordinates of Vegas package"}
}
```